# write() to /dev/ttyAMA0 always returns 0

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to work with RPi serial interface.
Call to write() while trying to write to /dev/ttyAMA0 always returnes 0 using following code.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
  struct termios cur,bak;
  int fd,count;
  char *tx_buf;

  tx_buf = (char*) malloc(20);
  fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  tcgetattr(fd,&cur);     /* store current attribute */
  bak = cur;    /* backup structure */

  cur.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
  cur.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
  cur.c_oflag = 0;
  cur.c_lflag = 0;

  tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);  
  tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&cur);

  /* TX */
  strncpy(tx_buf,"hello",5);
  count = write(fd,tx_buf,5);
  printf("wrotten:%5d\n",count);

  tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&bak);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

What can be the problem? Where should I start to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Try removing the `O_NDELAY` option from the open syscall; i.e. perform blocking instead of non-blocking writes.  Or insert a `tcdrain()` syscall after the `write()`.  IOW don't use non-blocking I/O if you don't have to. That terminal initialization code might have worked for the original author, but it's not portable.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)